# google earth fetchKml timeout

Tags: timeout, kml, large-files, google-earth-plugin

I am calling the goolge earth api function 'fetchKml' via javascript. When fetching large files firefox gives me a popup that says "A script on this page may be busy, or it may have stopped responding. You can stop the script now, open the script in the debugger, or let the script continue."

I noticed a similar question on google groups issue 331 ('fetchKml fails on slower connections or fast connections and large KML/KMZ files'). Well alas - that issue was in 2009. Now is 2012. How do I progromatically get the file to load without getting the timeout issue?

Thank you.

Comment: You might try and rewrite your kml/kmz files using KmlNetworkLinks. While you cannot manipulate the kml with networklinks before displaying on the earth, its very fast and minimal in size.  https://developers.google.com/earth/articles/earthapikml

Answer (score 1):

The root cause is that [fetchKml](https://developers.google.com/earth/documentation/reference/google_earth_namespace#afca518f43d5f863b254c5fa23a5967f2) is synchronous. It will block until the KML file is fetched over the network, parsed, and the content it specifies is loaded in the plugin. If any of these steps take too long (the server is slow to respond, the file is very large, the content is overly complicated) and so the function call takes too long, it will trip the slow script warning in browsers, which usually just triggers on a simple time-based watchdog loop.

There are a few ways to work around this:

- The simplest way is to split your content into several separate
  KML files and load each of them, maybe yielding with a `setTimeout` in
  between each `fetchKml()` call. This won't help if your main problem is
  latency, but since you said this was happening with large KML files,
  that probably isn't the case here.
- The idiomatic way is to use [NetworkLinks](https://developers.google.com/kml/documentation/kmlreference#networklink) in your KML to load
  these other files. The first `fetchKml` call will be synchronous, but
  then (depending on how the [update mechanism is set](https://developers.google.com/kml/documentation/updates)) subsequent
  content will be loaded by the plugin in its own time, without
  blocking the javascript execution thread.
- Finally, there is the take-matters-into-your-own-hand way. You can
  use the browsers' native `XMLHttpRequest` functionality to load the KML
  file, which is asynchronous by default. When the file is loaded, your
  callback function will be notified, and then you can use
  [parseKml()](https://developers.google.com/earth/documentation/reference/interface_g_e_plugin#acd35e260277fb0ffb86b5b2a962551da) to load that file in the plugin and display its
  content. Note that `parseKml` is also synchronous, so it will block
  while the file is being parsed and the content created, but usually
  that is a very fast step compared to downloading the file in the
  first place.