# Using Google Earth API and KML in order to fetchkml and embed as an online 3d map

Tags: javascript, html, kml, google-earth-plugin

I have written a KML file that I want to embed in order to create a 3D map online. 
I have been able to successfully use the Google Earth Plug in to text the file and embed it into Blogger and I have validated my code. However, when I try to use the plug in and embed the code into my website, it doesn't work. I have hosted the kml file on my server, which also hosts site that I want to post the map onto. (So, the KML file isn't coming from a computer but is hosted on a server).

Because the Google Plug in isn't working to embed the file, I am trying to figure out why. 
I have followed the instructions according to the KML developer guidelines and added the functions (see below)

```
<script>
<html>
  <head>
    <script src="https://www.google.com/jsapi?key=YOURAPIKEY"></script>
    <script>
      google.load('earth','1', {'other_params':'sensor=false'});

      var ge = null;

      function init() {
        google.earth.createInstance('map3d', initCallback, failureCallback);
      }

      function initCallback(pluginInstance) {
        ge = pluginInstance;
        ge.getWindow().setVisibility(true);
      }

      function failureCallback() {
        // we can do something here if there's an error
      }
    </script>

  </head>
  <body onload="init()" id="body">
    <div id="map3d" style="width: 500px; height: 500px;"></div>
  </body>
</html>
```

However, I am not sure what I am missing. In order for the Google API to work, is there more Javascript that needs to be added to the kml to work? I believe I need to perfect the kml, including code to fetchkml, but I have hit a dead end with the code. I have read many questions on the Google Earth API and kml and cannot find a clear answer to why this works on Blogger but not on my site. 
I have permissions on my site so that is a non-issue.

A few Stackoverflow questions that have helped but not clearly answered my questions:

[Google Earth API, KML on local Web Server](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13251562/google-earth-api-kml-on-local-web-server)

[Google earth fetchKml timeout](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11562694/google-earth-fetchkml-timeout)

Any assistance in helping me integrate my kml with the Google Earth API and javascript is appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The code looks AOK apart from the line

`<script src="https://www.google.com/jsapi?key=YOURAPIKEY"></script>`

Really it should either have *your api key* in the query, or else simply be

`<script src="https://www.google.com/jsapi"></script>`

As it is, it could be that you are simply getting an invalid API key error.

If that doesn't solve it could you post a link to your actual site where it isn't working?

Comment: Editing the code to <script src="https://www.google.com/jsapi"></script> helped. I can now get the html file to show the Google Earth API in 3D in my testing environment. However, I now I have a different problem- "addsidedatabase" is not pulling up my data. Are there specific parameters or file types for such databases? My current database is a .kml file.

Comment: Glad that worked, you should perhaps consider marking my answer accepted. As for the other issue - you would need to ask a new question. If you do - be sure post a link to an example of the problem or at least include an example of the code. You make no reference to a side DB in your post so I don't know what you are talking about...